# Will it ever be possible to run all web traffic via HTTPS?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, encryption, https

I was considering what would it take (technologically) to move all the web traffic to HTTPS. I thought that computers are getting faster, and faster, so some time from now it will be possible to run all traffic via HTTPS without any noticeable cost.

But then again, I thought, encryption strength will have to evolve to counter the loss of security. If computers get 10x faster, encryption will have to be 10x stronger, or it will be 10x easier to break.

So, will we ever be able to encrypt *all* web traffic "for free"?

**Edit:** I'm asking only about the logic of performance increases in computing vs encryption. If we can use the same crypto algorhytms and keys in 20 years, they will consume a far lower percentage of the overall computing capacity of a server (or client), and in effect, that will make it "free" to encrypt and sign everything that we transmit over networks.

Comment: The guys who sell ssl certs will love that.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: Of course, cost of certification would have to be much lower, and the process would have to be very simple. My question is only about the effect of rising computer performance.

Comment: @Achilles: I don't think it's fully appropriate on either site, but I was hoping on someone good at crypto adding a quick answer.

Comment: State department wouldn't like that idea

Comment: Sure.  Why would you want to?

Comment: Because I think it makes Internet more secure and reliable for the users. Why _wouldn't_ you want to do that?

Comment: The idea behind modern encryption algorithms is that they're incredibly hard to break by brute force, and increasing clock speed by a factor of a thousand on billion-core CPUs isn't going to make them breakable.  There is the danger of a cryptanalysis breakthrough, but that's something different entirely.

Comment: @David: But do you think that means crypto keys will not get any longer? Do you think the cost of encryption will get lower in the future?

Comment: Using crypto is already pretty fast, particularly considering that we're using CPU cycles vs. data transmission.  Crypto keys do not need to get longer.  I don't think there's any technical reason why this is impractical.

Comment: @David: Thank you. I would accept that as the answer :)

Comment: All else being equal, if you use 2x the number of bits in the key, you just SQUARED the amount of work needed to break it via brute force, while normal encryption and decryption would be just around 2-4 times slower. Brute-force being 10x faster just loses you around 3.3 bits of key strength. You should be more worried about advances in the math the crypto people use than about computers becoming faster.

Comment: @CesarB: I'm usually more worried about parsing inputs correctly :D But that probably means that it's possible (and in my view, very probable) that some day we will encrypt everything we transmit.

Comment: Maybe it's too late to answer, but some ISPs here provide (for extra price) antivirus service that inspects your traffic. With SSL all over the place it will be impossible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the big issues with using HTTPS is that its considered secure and so most web browsers don't do any caching, or at least do very limited caching.

Without the cache, you'll notice that HTTPS pages load significantly slower and a non-encrypted page would.

HTTPS should be used to protect sensitive information.

I have no idea about the CPU impact of running everything through SSL.  I would say that on the client side, the CPU isn't an issue since most workstations are running idle most of the time anyway.  The big program would be on the web server side due to the sheer number of concurrent requests that are being handled.

In order to get to the point that SSL is basically 'free', you'd have to have dedicated hardware for encryption (which already exists today).

**EDIT**: Based on the comments, the question's author suggests this is the answer he was looking for :

> Using crypto is already pretty fast,
>   particularly considering that we're
>   using CPU cycles vs. data
>   transmission. Crypto keys do not need
>   to get longer. I don't think there's
>   any technical reason why this is
>   impractical.
>   -[David Thornley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14148/david-thornley)

**UPDATE**: I just read that [Google's SPDY protocol](http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper) (designed to replace HTTP) looks like it will use SSL on every connection.  So, it looks like Google thinks that it's possible!

> To make SSL the underlying transport
>   protocol, for better security and
>   compatibility with existing network
>   infrastructure. Although SSL does
>   introduce a latency penalty, we
>   believe that the long-term future of
>   the web depends on a secure network
>   connection. In addition, the use of
>   SSL is necessary to ensure that
>   communication across existing proxies
>   is not broken.

Comment: This was discussed in detail on a recent Security Now podcast. See http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-198.txt and search for "couple of cons that were not discussed"

Comment: If HTTPS was used for all communications, we would use other means (like Expires headers) to regulate caching. My question is only about the logic of performance increases in computing vs encryption.

Answer (score 3):

Chris Thompson mentions browser caching, but that's easily fixable in the browser. What isn't fixable on switching everything to HTTPS is proxy caching. Because HTTPS is encrypted end-to-end, transparent HTTP proxies don't work. There are a lot of places where transparent proxying can speed things up (for instance at NAT boundaries).

Dealing with the additional bandwidth from losing transparent proxying is probably doable - allegedly HTTP traffic is trivial compared with p2p anyway, so it's not as if transparent proxies are the only thing keeping the internet online. It will hit latency irrevocably, and make a slashdotting even worse than it is currently. But then with cloud hosting, both those might be dealt with by tech. Of course "secure server" takes on a different meaning with cloud hosting, or even with other forms of de-centralisation of content across the network like akamai.

I don't think the CPU overhead is that significant. Sure, if your server is currently CPU bound at least some of the time, then switching all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS will kill it stone dead. Some servers may decide that HTTPS is not worth the monetary cost of a CPU that can handle the load, and they will prevent literally *everyone* adopting it. But I doubt it will be a major barrier for long. For instance, Google has crossed it already and happily serves apps (although not searches) as https without fuss. And the more work servers are doing per connection, the less proportional extra work is required to SSL-secure that connection. SSL can be and is hardware accelerated where necessary.

There's also the management/economic problem that HTTPS relies on trusted CAs, and trusted CAs cost money. There are other ways to design a PKI than the one SSL actually uses, but there are reasons SSL works how it does. For example SSH places the responsibility on the user to obtain a key fingerprint from the server by a secure side-channel, and [this is the result](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-hostkeys): some users don't think that level of inconvenience is justified by its security purpose. If users don't want security, then they won't get it unless it's impossible for them to avoid it.

If users just auto-click "accept" for untrusted SSL certificates, then you pretty much might as well not have it, since these days a man-in-the-middle attack is not significantly more difficult than plain eavesdropping. So, again, there's a significant block of servers which just aren't interesting in paying for (working) HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

1. Encryption would not have to get 10x stronger in the sense that you would not need to use 10x more bits.  The difficulty of brute force cracking increases exponentially with an increasing key length.  At most key lengths would have to get slightly longer.
2. What would be the point of running **all** traffic through SSL, even stuff where there is obviously no advantage?  This seems incredibly wasteful.  For example, it seems ridiculous to download a Linux distro through SSL.

Comment: 1. But is the computing cost of encryption symmetric with the cost of brute-force? 2. I'm asking about a situation where the cost of encryption is so low, it makes sense to use it always -- Big Brother could swap in some spying code into your Debian torrent.

Comment: Because if everything is encrypted there is no 'special' traffic so no sigint - I can't learn anything about your radical network of Joel fans by looking at who you send encrypted messages to.

Comment: Why do you think it is ridiculous to distribute software via a secured channel?

Comment: Because there's no privacy to protect and it wastes CPU cycles.

Comment: But you might want to assert the confidentiality, integrity, and authenticity of a software distribution where HTTPS (or BITS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service#List_of_non-Microsoft_applications_that_use_BITS) might be a fit.

Comment: And, for example, you might not want your government to know what you download.

Comment: @Pies:  No, the cost of using ciphers when you know the key is not particularly related to the cost when not knowing the key.  Modern ciphers are essentially proof against brute force as they stand.

Comment: @David: thank you, I think that's the answer I'm looking for -- the cost of encryption will get much lower in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 2):

The cost isn't that great nowadays.

Also...having a computer that is 10x faster will in no way make it necessary to change encryption.  AES (a common encryption for SSL) is strong enough that it would take a very very long time to break.

Comment: What if someone finds a weakness in AES that makes it a million times easier to break it? Wouldn't using a 16kbit keys be safer?

Comment: If they find a weakness sufficient to make breaking it practical, adding more bits to the key isn't going to help much.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be possible?  YES
Will it be advisable? NO

For a few reasons.

- extra cpu cycles on server and client would use more power which incurs cost and emissions
- ssl certs would be required for every server
- it's useless to encrypt data that doesn't need to be hidden

Comment: 1) Computer cycles are getting cheaper every day. 2) Doesn't matter for my question. 3) If you just encrypt valuable data, it makes it easy to spot and focus efforts on. If everyone encrypts everything, it makes attacks far more difficult.

Comment: So, why would there be a problem with every server having a certificate?  They aren't expensive or onerous to generate.  Right now, what's expensive is buying a cert that will be recognized by common web browsers in their default configuration; to put this another way, what you're paying for is not encryption but authentication.

Comment: @pies 1. cheaper != free and imagine the sum cost if EVERY server and EVERY client were doing SSL for EVERY transaction 2. This is why I said possible yes advisable no 3. if you encrypt everything you might get lazy with security because "it's all https"

@david not expensive != free

Comment: @Hardwareguy: What if you'd get a free SSL certificate with every domain you buy?

Comment: @Hardwareguy:  Certificates are, essentially, free.  You can generate your own, no problem.  What costs is establishing some sort of connection between you and your certificate.

Comment: @Pies: good plan. Presumably signed by the domain registrar, it's about the same problem as IPSec, which is very hard but needs doing anyway. I like the way that Google appengine uses subdomains of appspot.com to provide cheap and easy SSL.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the answer is no.  The main reason for this is that if you consider how many pages have items from multiple sources that would each have to use https and have a valid certificate that I don't think would work for some of the big companies that would have to change all their links.

It isn't a bad idea and maybe some Web x.0 would have more secure communications by default, but I don't think http will be that protocol.

Just to give a couple of examples, though I am from Canada which may affect how these sites render:

www.msn.com :

- atdmt.com
- s-msn.com
- live.com

www.cnn.com :

- revsci.net
- cnn.net
- turner.com
- dl-rms.com

Those were listed through "NoScript" which notes this page has code from "google-analytics.com" and "quantserve.com" besides the stackoverflow.com for a third example of this.

Comment: But if everyone used HTTPS, so would those ad servers etc. My question is whether it is possible to lower the cost of it so much, that the marginal profit of security is worth the expense.

Comment: It is probable for the monetary cost to be lowered but consider what kind of transition would happen as you wouldn't imagine every server around the world switching to HTTPS simultaneously, would you?

Comment: It doesn't have to happen all at once. For example Google Analytics javascript file is available both via http and https.

Comment: However, if a site uses both http and https there is a dialog that will pop-up about downloading non-secure items that would be a nightmare and quite likely to happen as each webmaster has to know if all their image and javascript includes and other stuff happens in unison.  Parts of it do have to happen at once is my point here.

Comment: @JB: That's because right now http is the default. If https was the default, there wouldn't be a problem (i.e. there are no warnings about secure items on an insecure page.)

Comment: I wonder if that would encourage another form of encryption eventually as some may not feel that it is safe or if governments would want a way to eavesdrop would security software makers create back doors that would be exploited by hackers, hmm....

Comment: If open source becomes the default standard for most software, you don't think there will be more vulnerabilities found?  That seems a little naive to me.

Comment: vulnerability != backdoor. Building backdoors into open source software is possible, but much more difficult (100x, according to Pies...) than the backdoors in proprietary software that you suggested. A high proportion of web servers already are running open-source LAMP stacks already, and a decent proportion of clients using open-source browsers (20%+). So if open source results in more vulns, then those vulns are already here. I'm not panicking :-)

Answer (score 0):

A major difference with https is that a session is kept open until you close it. Saves a lot of hassle with session cookies but puts a load on the server.

How long should google keep the https session with you alive after you send a query?

Do you want a persistent connection to every popup ad?

Comment: I would expect that by that time the software would be capable of handling that kind of thing, because, well, everyone would be doing it. I'm just asking if it's at all possible logically.

Comment: Software can always handle it - it's the other effects, like session tracking that you need to consider.

Comment: Servers can kill SSL sessions if they want to recover the associated resources. SSLv3 only has its own close message because using TCP FIN allows an attacker to insert that packet without the client realising that the server didn't intend to close (called a truncation attack). And servers can keep plain HTTP connections open with Keep-Alive if they want to. It's just that SSL handshake is considerably more expensive than TCP handshake, so keeping connections open is more valuable.